# pyttsx3 is spelling out words

Tags: python, pycharm, text-to-speech, pyttsx3

I'm trying to take a dataframe :

`NeuroScience_df = pd.read_csv('ns_def_test.csv', delimiter='-')`

and run it thru a function that randomly iterates through the dataframe and prints out variables in each row while waiting for user input:

```
def df_values_to_vars():
    func_that_shuffles_index = func_that_shuffles_index(NeuroScience_df)
    the_results = ''  # Create an empty string to store the results
    for _, row in NeuroScience_df.loc[shuffled_index].iterrows():
        name = f"name {row['name']}"
        description = f"description {row['description']}"
        the_results += f"{name}\n{description}\n{'-' * 100}\n"
        print(the_results)
        _ = input("Press enter to continue: ")

    return the_results
results = df_values_to_vars()
```

and then, convert the results of the `df_values_to_vars()` function to text to speech.

```
def convert_df_values_to_speech(df_func):
    results = df_func()  # Call the provided function to get the results

    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.setProperty("rate", 200)  # Speed of speech
    engine.setProperty("volume", 0.8)  # Volume level (0.0 to 1.0)

    voices = engine.getProperty("voices")
    for voice in voices:
        if "english" in voice.languages:
            engine.setProperty("voice", voice.id)
            break

    for result in results:
        engine.say(results)

    engine.runAndWait()
```

But in the function , `convert_df_values_to_speech` ,pyttsx3 spells out each letter instead of saying a sentence normally. How can I fix this?

Comment: It looks like `convert_df_values_to_speech` returns a single string. So when you do `for result in results`, you iterate character by character and give the speech engine one character at a time. The `convert_df_values_to_speech` function should probably instead return a list of strings?